# Are all salts completely dissociated in solution when put in smaller amounts than their molar solubility?

Tags: aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry, solubility, solutions, concentration

From what I understand, the solubility is given in terms of molar solubility (or $\pu{K_{sp}}$), from which it can be easily calculated). Indeed, the saturation point represents the maximum amount of a slightly soluble substance in an aqueous solution that solubilizes (dissociates).
Therefore, in extremely small amounts even very sparingly soluble salts with extremely small molar solubilities (and $\pu{K_{sp}'}$) can be completely ionized. For instance, $\ce{HgS}$ is one of the least soluble inorganic substances with a molar solubility of about $\ce{10^{-27}}$. Now, if I put up to $\ce{10^{-27}}$ moles of HgS in 1L of water, will it be completely dissolved into $\ce{Hg^{2+}}$ and $\ce{S^{2-}}$?

Comment: HgCl2 is reportedly in large extent covalent. Some salts forms ionic pairs, like MgSO4 in sea water. Other may form charged or neutral complexes.

Comment: This is an equilibrium process and so to calculate the extent of reaction you can use the usual methods starting with different initial amounts.

Comment: A solubility of $\ce{10^{-27}}$ M corresponds to $1$ atom $\ce{Hg}$ and $1$ atom $\ce{S}$ in $10^4$ liters, or in $10$ metric tons. This is practically zero atom per litre. This amount is not detectable.

Comment: You cannot put less than $\pu{\frac{1}{N_\mathrm{A}} mol}$ of anything anywhere, as it would be less than 1 object.

Comment: Yes. Ksp describes a saturated solution. If from dissolution of a salt stoichiometric quantities of cation & anion will be dissolved ("in solution')

Answer (score 1):

We should not expect salts with multiply charged ions to be completely dissociated in aqueous solution except, perhaps, at very low concentrations. The comments refer to magnesium sulfate, a technical reference for which is [Sebastiani et al.[1]](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/cp/c9cp06845g). Note that in this case the paired ions are not in direct contact but separated by solvent molecules, so it's an "outer-sphere" association.

**Reference**

Federico Sebastiani, Ana Vila Verde, Matthias Heyden, Gerhard Schwaab, and  Martina Havenith (2020). "Cooperativity and ion pairing in magnesium sulfate aqueous solutions from the dilute regime to the solubility limit". *Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.*, **22**, 12140-12153.